# How to Set deafult values in adminhtml form magento

Tags: forms, magento, adminhtml

I am looking to add default values in textboxes in add product form in magento?Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Magento EAV attributes can have default values, which will appear pre-entered in corresponding **adminhtml** forms. The default value of an attribute is stored in table `eav_attribute`, column `default_value`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! But in some of the custom fields we want values according to the admin logged-In. Supposed if there are 3-4 admin account of the site.Based upon which admin is logged in Vlaues should appear in custom fields like telephone,Email etc.